# Get data from firestore updating

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I have this function:

```
  getDataById(collection: string, key: string) {
return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
  this.afs.collection(collection).doc(key).ref.get().then(resp => resolve(resp), err => reject(err));
});
```

}

For instance:
In firebase I have the field name with value 'José' when I call this function I receive Jose but the value chances automatically to null after read. I made a full review to understand if come function was changing the value but the problem happen only when I read the value from firestore.

"firebase": "5.8.6",
"@angular/fire": "^5.1.2",

Answer (score 1):

Before logout from the app I was send an update and close the connection before the promise return. When I return to the app firestore was completing the save data, during the read the data overwriting the server side data and returning an old data.